# How do I compute the average and RMS of a series of triangular pulses?

Tags: power, current, diodes, math, rms

[image: **Diode waveform graph**]
I'm trying to calculate the Average and RMS values of the current through a diode with the waveform image attached. I'm struggling to work out which equations to use. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Which parts of the Wikipedia articles are you having trouble with?

Comment: So which forum did you ask? Take note that this is a question and answer site and not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

Average current is the sum of the current over a cycle, divided by the length of the cycle

Your current is a triangle with \$I_{peak}=1.8\$ amps, and a base of about \$t_{on}=.9\$ divisions, so you get an area of \$\frac{1}{2}BH=.81\$ (some unit of charge, since it's current x time). You then spread that out over \$T=3.7\$ divisions (charge/time = current again), which gives an average of .22 amps.

Alternately, if you work the calculus to get a general form for the average current of a series of triangular pulses:

\$I(t)=I_{peak}(1-\frac{t}{t_{on}})\$ between \$t=0\$ and \$t=t_{on}\$, and zero elsewhere.

\$I_{AVG}=\frac{\int_{0}^{T}{I(t) dt}}{T}\$ by definition of mean.

Substituting in I(t) from above:

\$I_{AVG}=\frac{\int_{0}^{T}{I_{peak}(1-\frac{t}{t_{on}}) dt}}{T}\$.

Rearranging and executing integral:

\$I_{AVG}=\frac{I_{peak}}{T}(t-\frac{t^2}{2t_{on}})]^{t_{on}}_{0}\$

\$I_{AVG} = \frac{I_{peak}D}{2}\$

Where \$D=\frac{t_{on}}{T}\$. This gives us the same answer as above, for your duty cycle of about .25.

RMS current is a little more complicated.

\$I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{\int_{0}^{T}{I(t)^2 dt}}{T}}\$ by definition of RMS.

Substituting in I(t) from above:

\$I_{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{\int_{0}^{t_{on}}{I_{peak}^2(1-\frac{t}{t_{on}})^2 dt}}{T}}\$

Rearranging:

\$I_{RMS}=\frac{I_{peak}}{\sqrt{T}}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{t_{on}}{(1-\frac{t}{t_{on}})^2 dt}}\$

\$I_{RMS}=\frac{I_{peak}}{\sqrt{T}}\sqrt{
\int_{0}^{t_{on}}{(1-\frac{2t}{t_{on}} + \frac{t^2}{t_{on}^2}) dt}
}\$

\$I_{RMS}=\frac{I_{peak}}{\sqrt{T}}\sqrt{
(t-\frac{t^2}{t_{on}} + \frac{t^3}{3t_{on}^2})]^{t_{on}}_{0}
}\$

\$I_{RMS}=\frac{I_{peak}}{\sqrt{T}}\sqrt{
\frac{t_{on}}{3}
}\$

\$I_{RMS} = \frac{I_{peak}\sqrt{D}}{\sqrt{3}}\$

So your RMS is about .52 amps.

Comment: I've never seen that formula before but it looks specific to a certain waveform. Where did you get it? Which of the OP's waveforms does it apply to?

Comment: @transistor I've updated my answer to give a detailed derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle of taking an average (in this case the artihmetic mean) is:

1. Take every point of a single period of your waveform
2. Add together all those values
3. Divide by the number of values

\$ average = \frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... x_n) \$

The basic principle of RMS is:

1. Take every point of a single period of your waveform
2. Square that value
3. Add together all those values
4. Divide by the number of values
5. Take the square root

\$ rms = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + ... x_n^2)} \$

Comment: Leave out step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your triangle wave current is about 1.7Amp peak at a 25% duty cycle. The RMS current of a continuous triangle wave is:
Irms(continuous) = 1/sqrt3 x Ipeak. 
This is multiplied by the sqrt of the duty:
Irms = Irms(cont) x sqrt(duty) = 1/sqrt3 * sqrt(duty) * Ipeak.
so, in your case Irms = 0.577 * sqrt(0.25) * 1.7Amp = 491mArms.

The average current you can easily calculate from the waveform if you estimate it to be a triangle wave. I won't help you do simple algebra. If you're an engineer you should know this.

Comment: Do not assume the OP is skilled at all the types of math to solve a series of equations. After all, the OP is asking a question where the math to get the answer was not understood. Avoid 'scolding' the OP. Those with high rep scores will do so if needed.